# Can I change "recent call" stack when raise exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, raise

When I raise exception in codes, Python shows call stack. The last call is where raise exception code I wrote. But it's not an important code itself.
Can I change call stack to hide the "raise ..." code?

My code:

```py
def myFunc(var):
  if isinstance(var, int) is True:
    print('var:', var)
  else:
    raise TypeError('Invalid type.')


def wrapperFunc(var):
  myFunc(var)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  wrapperFunc('abc')
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/snoma/study/python/etc/trackImageEdge/exceptTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    wrapperFunc('abc')
  File "C:/Users/snoma/study/python/etc/trackImageEdge/exceptTest.py", line 9, in wrapperFunc
    myFunc(var)
  File "C:/Users/snoma/study/python/etc/trackImageEdge/exceptTest.py", line 5, in myFunc
    raise TypeError('Invalid type.')
TypeError: Invalid type.
```

The last call is "raise TypeError..." code and I think it's not necessary information. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `traceback` module to limit info from the back trace

```
import sys
import traceback

def c():
  a = 1/0

def b():
  c()

def a():
  b()

try:
  a()
except:
  t, v, bt = sys.exc_info()
  traceback.print_tb(bt, limit=2)
  traceback.print_tb(bt)
```

**Playing around with stack trace**

You can play around with the shape of stack, but I think it's not possible to remove the initial cause of the error

```
import sys
import traceback

def c(): 1/0
def b(): c()
def a(): b()


t = None
v = None
bt = None

try:
  a()
except:
  t, v, bt = sys.exc_info()

bt = None  # you can play here with changing bt.tb_next order

raise exc.with_traceback(bt)
```

Comment: I want to hide call stack when raise(callee code), but not try ... except ...(caller code). Caller maybe doesn't know what happen in callee.